# Play Framework dependency injection Object vs @Singleton Class

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

Play Framework 2.4 has support for Google Guice Dependency Injection

What is the advantage of using

```
@Singleton class A
```

instead of

```
object A
```

for singletons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see three advantages of using `@Singleton class` over `object` if A has no dependencies:

1. If you wanted to test `A`, and declare it as `@Singleton class` you have the option of subclassing it to mock out some of the functions in your test, whereas this is not possible with an `object`.
2. If you use `object`, it is very tempting for clients of `A` to reference it directly, leading to a strongly coupled system, but using `@Singleton class` forces them to think about where `A` is instantiated, probably leading to a more decoupled design.
3. If you later change your mind, and allow multiple instances of `A`, the refactoring will be much easier to do if you chose to use `@Singleton class`.

If `A` has dependencies, however, using `@Singleton class` allows them to be dependency injected on construction, whereas with an object this is only possible if you declare the dependencies as mutable (eg: a `var` with getter/setter methods) .